# Vertical Mobile Scrolling - Fixed Navigation Menu Lag

Tags: javascript, menu, fixed, lag

I am currently working on a mobile version of a website which has a navigation menu at the top of the home page. I am using jquery smooth scroll in this nav menu, so that when a user selects a topic from the menu, it scrolls nicely to that particular item which is located further down the page. This works brilliantly, and I have no issues with it.

However, I am also using some code I found on this site which allows for the nav menu to become fixed at the top of the page once the user scrolls past a certain point. (160px in my case) That code is here:

```
/* Dynamic top menu positioning
     *
     */

    var num = 160; //number of pixels before modifying styles

    $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > num) {
            $('.framecont').addClass('fixed');
        }
        else {
            $('.framecont').removeClass('fixed');
        }
    });
```

And here is the CSS for .framecont and .fixed if necessary:

```
.framecont{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
    border-top: 1px solid grey;
    box-shadow: 0 -55px 1px -7px #FFFFFF inset;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 110px;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 99;
    }

.fixed {
border-bottom: 5px solid grey;
border-top: 5px solid grey;
box-shadow: 0 0 30px #000;
padding-bottom: 10px;
padding-top: 5px;
position:fixed;
top:0;
}
```

When a user selects an item from the nav menu, the jquery smooth scroll kicks in, (as well as the code above) and immediately snaps the menu to the top of the page once the scroll has reached past 160px. This is great. But when a user manually scrolls past 160px on the page, (using their finger to scroll instead of selecting a nav menu item) there is significant lag before the menu appears fixed at the top of the page. As a user manually flicks his/her finger down the page, the scroll has to come to a complete stop (and the user has to remove his/her finger from the screen) before the menu appears fixed at the top of the page.

This lag is the problem I am trying to solve. I would love the menu to immediately appear fixed at the top of the window when a user manually scrolls past 160px, just as it does when a user selects a nav menu item and the jquery smooth scroll kicks in. Is this possible?

If you haven't figured it out already, I am VERY new to javascript and coding in general. This is my first time asking a question on this site, so I apologize in advance if I have not followed proper etiquette in any way.

Comment: This is a known problem with fixed position items in iOS. If you find any solution to this, please let me know here: https://github.com/underpull/Balloon/issues/2

It seems like the solution freddywang suggests in that link is to go with something other than native scrolling (such as iScroll). Good luck!

Comment: Yeah, even the github folks from your link seem to be going with the 'wait until Apple fixes it' approach.

Comment: Oh, haha. I just realized the github folks are... well, you basically. Lol.

Comment: Hahaha yeah that's my repo. :-)